# How to make a swipeable collection view cell to show delete button Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

How can I make a swipeable collection view cell to show a delete button in swift?

I have a function to delete a cell with this code

```
func reset(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    let cell = sender.view as! UICollectionViewCell
    let i = self.collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)!.item
    deleteDateFromArray(i)
    deleteImageFromArray(i)
    deleteSinceLabelFromArray(i)
    self.collectionView.reloadData() // replace favoritesCV with your own collection view.
}
```

Which is called with this gesture

```
let cSelector = #selector(DateMenuViewController.reset(_:))
    let UpSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: cSelector )
    UpSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(UpSwipe)
```

But I would like to have a gesture pretty much exactly the same as in the mail app, that is slide to the left on a cell and it will show a delete button?

Thanks

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help.

Comment: All I need is any answer, or a link to a tutorial, because all I can find is referred to UITableView

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Made an edit, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `UICollectionView` provides that convenience (you probably saw it in `UITableView`). It means you'll probably have to implement it by yourself.